# Value of a German Industrial PhD in India

Tags: phd, industry

I have an offer for a full time job with a contract for 3 years in which I would be a PhD candidate in Germany at a reputed firm. I would have a supervisor at a technical university besides a supervisor at the company. The area of specialization is wireless communications. My plan is to go back to India in a couple of years and start working as an Assistant Professor in an IIT or some reputed institution in India.

Will this PhD have the same importance as compared to a PhD done at a university when looking for such Professorship in India?

Answer (score 4):

As to address the second part of your question, almost all IIT's have a strict requirement that after your PhD (Which can be from Germany) you need to be a post doctoral fellow for a minimum of three years (assuming you took 3 years to do your PhD, bringing your total experience to 6 years). It is also mandated that this must be outside your home country.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Do you have a source for this? The formal requirements do not generally seem to mention that a postdoc is necessary.

Comment: I did my PhD from IIT-Bombay (graduated 2018) and when I enquired about joining the department, this is what I was told. -sd

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Only a university may *award* a doctorate, so your study would be done in cooperation with one or more supervisors from one of the German universities and you will be enrolled at this university.

Perhaps you won't have any mandatory teaching duties when doing an industry-sponsored PhD, but it will be very worthwhile to do some teaching anyway. It's a valuable skill you should not miss out on.

One is not necessarily any better or worse than the other.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are going very much in a good trajectory. As for getting an Assistant Professor job in India, do not worry. Doors would certainly be open here. Keep doing the good work that you are doing and you will certainly be rewarded.